# allow 2 machines to communciate each with their own network?

Tags: switch, router, network, gateway

2 networks. Network 1 local and i want to be able to receive and send information to network 2 which is at a remote site, branch site. How do i go about connecting both networks so that both machines can communicate. I do not wish to use a VPN.

Comment: Unfortunately, your question is too broad to answer as asked. We need a lot more detail, such as a good network description or diagram, the network device models, and the network device configurations. Speculation and guessing are off-topic here.

Answer (score 1):

If you don't use a VPN then the other option is to lease a line that will connect the two sites.

Depending on your country/location different option(dark fiber, mpls network...) may be available (or not). You need to find vendors that provide this kind of service, beginning with your current ISP.

Note that in any case, this will cost much more than a VPN solution, but you have better quality (guaranteed bandwidth, stable latency, SLA...)

Comment: Will i not be able to do it over the internet if i did not use a VPN? any alternatives? i can enable it via the firewall etc. I want to be able to communicate with a specific IP address and port on the second network which is external and at the second site.

Comment: @AMD this is very different from the title of your question. Yes it can be done with NAT for a single (or a few) port, even if insecure.

Comment: What are the steps please? What would i have to do to get it to work. I need communication between the machines. I have set machine B which is located on a different network with a static IP address and it will be sending data to machine A but i need to access the IPs and ports and vice versa for both machines.

Comment: You need to add NAT rule on the firewall of the machine A site. The exact way to do it depends on the firewall used.

Comment: so a NAT rule on machine A will then allow access to machine B and vice versa? I have a phone system based at machine B which needs to send data over to machine A using its IP address and port.